# Why does Mariadb gets stuck at "Opening tables" when DESC command is used when under load?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

In our production servers, whenever we have production peak times, we often encounter following command stuck.

```
461720  c6b2c772b91fd3d8    wra01.ntex.com:33664    c6b2c772b91fd3d8    Query   24  Opening tables  DESC `tabSMS Alert` 0.000
```

Is DESC a locking command which has to wait for something?

Comment: Desc is the desctibe statement (not command) that gets the list of columns in a table. That works on metadata, so cannot lock anything.

Comment: And i can't even find the documentation on opening tables anywhere. Can anyone enlighten the path to me?

Comment: It is a step internal to mysql, so you will not find much documentation on it. The show processlist statement's doc mentions it.